# Can you provide an example quantum system that violates Bell's inequality?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement, bells-inequality

I am self-learning QM. I am reading this paper about Bell's theorem https://arxiv.org/pdf/1212.5214.pdf and having difficult to understand the quantum system example in the paper that violates Bell's inequality.

I'll describe the setup in short here. Refer to the paper for the full details.

Consider 2 identical coins say X and Y, each with 3 0-1 valued properties A, B, C. Because 2 coins are identical we have $P(X_A=Y_A)=P(X_B=Y_B)=P(X_C=Y_C)=1$. Then 2 coins are boxed and sent to Alice and Bob separately. If the system is local and counterfactual-definite, then upon opening the box $P(X_A=Y_B)+P(X_B=Y_C)+P(X_C=Y_A)>=1$ which is a form of Bell's inequality.

Then the author described a quantum system that violates the above inequality: an entangled
$|\Phi^+\rangle = (|00\rangle + |11\rangle)/\sqrt{2}$ and projects it to properties A, B, C with

$$
|a_0\rangle = |0\rangle \\
|a_1\rangle = |1\rangle \\
|b_0\rangle = \frac{1}{2}|0\rangle + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}|1\rangle \\
|b_1\rangle = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}|0\rangle - \frac{1}{2}|1\rangle \\
|c_0\rangle = \frac{1}{2}|0\rangle - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}|1\rangle \\
|c_1\rangle = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}|0\rangle + \frac{1}{2}|1\rangle \\
$$

Author says it is easy to check that
$$|\Phi^+\rangle = (|b_0b_0\rangle + |b_1b_1\rangle)/\sqrt{2}$$

My first question is how this is derived. In the most general form
$$|\Phi^+\rangle = \lambda_{00}|b_0b_0\rangle + \lambda_{01}|b_0b_1\rangle +\lambda_{10} |b_1b_0\rangle + \lambda_{11}|b_1b_1\rangle$$
Why cross terms are gone? I can't derive the claim using the $|b_0\rangle$ and $|b_1\rangle$ given above.

Then the author claims it is easy to find $P(X_A=Y_B)$ under this setting with
$$|\Phi^+\rangle = (|a_0\rangle (|b_0\rangle + \sqrt{3}|b_1\rangle ) + |a_1\rangle (\sqrt{3}|b_0\rangle -|b_1\rangle ))/2\sqrt{2}  $$

Again in the most general form
$$|\Phi^+\rangle = \gamma_{00}|a_0b_0\rangle + \gamma_{01}|a_0b_1\rangle +\gamma_{10} |a_1b_0\rangle + \gamma_{11}|a_1b_1\rangle$$
I am not sure how the coefficients are derived.

If you can provide other toy examples that can help me understand how an entangled quantum state violates Bell's inequality that is also fine. Thank you!

Comment: You write down $(|_0_0\rangle+|_1_1\rangle)/\sqrt{2}$ by using the expressions you have for $|_0\rangle$ and $|_1\rangle$ in terms of $|0\rangle,|1\rangle$ and multiply it out and cancel terms to get $(|00\rangle+|11\rangle)/\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: @alanf That's using the answer to derive the calculation. If I don't know the answer I'll also need to check $|b_0 b_1\rangle$ term which won't cancel out. Maybe I missed something...how do you know $|b_0 b_1\rangle$ is 0?

Comment: Nothing in my comment implies that $|b_0b_1\rangle$ is 0.

Comment: I think you meant to ask: How do you know that the coefficient on $|b_0 b_1>$ is zero when expanded in this "general form".  You can check this by calculating the inner product $<\Phi^+|b_0 b_1>$=0.  (Notice the inner product of the $|00>$ term cancels the inner product of the $|11>$ term.)

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can calculate each of these $\gamma$ coefficients by taking inner products.  For example, from your very last equation, you can take the inner product between $<a_0 b_0 |$ and each side of that equation.  You will quickly see that this leads to
$<a_0 b_0|\Phi^+> = \gamma_{00} <a_0 b_0 | a_0 b_0> = \gamma_{00}$.  (The other three terms on the right cancel because those four states are all orthogonal to each other; $<a_0 b_0 | a_0 b_1>=0$, etc.)